# Probability that sum of two random variables in [0, π] is less than π

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Using a random generator, I choose 2 angles at random from the interval (0,π).

I want to calculate the percentage of cases where I can choose a matching 3rd angle so that a triangle with these angles could be created.

Can you help me with how to calculate this please!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or explaining what you tried would be a big step forward! (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Comment: Have a look at [this video from MIT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqI69tdVJbY) tackling something very similar called the *broken stick experiment*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine the first number you choose on the $x$ axis and the second on the $y$ axis. We have the line $x + y = \pi$ in the plane and you are interested in the area below this line, but in the square where $ 0 \leq x \leq \pi$ and $0 \leq y \leq \pi$. Since this line cuts the square in half, that answer is $1/2$. (The number $\pi$ is a red herring, this would be true for any top value on your interval.)

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks a lot

Comment: hunter: Please read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standard

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think 100% of the time you will be able to choose a matching 3rd angle. This is because for any $x,y,z$ so that $x+y+z = 2\pi$ radians where $0< x,y,z < 2\pi$, there exists a triangle with angles $x,y,z$.

I think you might be thinking about the triangle inequality; there doesn't always exist a triangle with sides $x,y,z$ because you need $x+y>z, y+z>x, x+z > y$, but this doesn't apply for angles.

Comment: Shouldn't angles sum to $\pi$, not $2\pi$?

Comment: All right! Thanks you for help

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?noredirect=1#comment153047_33508